# python decoding base64 into a json file

Tags: python, json, base64, zlib

So I tried to compress a JSON file and decompress it using this [code](https://medium.com/@busybus/zipjson-3ed15f8ea85d) (the two built function)
the compressing process works fine, but I can't figure out how to decompress it back to JSON, so I can append more items to it.
this is what I have tried:

```
path = r"mypath.json"

print(json_zip(path))
with open(path, "w") as f:
    json.dump(json_zip(path), f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

with open(path, "r") as f:
    file_data = json.load(f)
print(json_unzip(file_data))
```

print output:

```
{'base64(zip(o))': 'eJwNyjEKgDAQBdGrLOn1AHYaUewEsftNiKuskawkInh7U80rxtgGWDOnDHTMSYBR9biY+iQvA4NEF31BN4sP5Voe9YGmuCuwObk+2tzjyOv9UUW2BGjrM2s0PzCOIWs='}
C:\Users\Beeri\Google Drive\Finance\BPicks\Stock Info\daily data copy - Copy\A.json
```

maybe I don't get the concept of decompression right, but I want the JSON to look like it was before.
the JSON itself looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-05-18 16:00:00",
        "open": 83.79,
        "low": 83.67,
        "high": 83.79,
        "close": 83.67,
        "volume": 1855946
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-05-18 15:59:00",
        "open": 83.815,
        "low": 83.77,
        "high": 83.83,
        "close": 83.79,
        "volume": 1822469
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-05-18 15:58:00",
        "open": 83.9,
        "low": 83.78,
        "high": 83.9,
        "close": 83.815,
        "volume": 1803855
    }
]
```

Comment: Right; you requested to `json_zip` the path to the file, not the contents of the file. Therefore, when you `json_unzip` the result, you get the path, not the contents. `json_zip` is expecting to receive the parsed json, like a `json.load` result.

Comment: worked! thank you very much post this as an answer so I can mark this as answered.

Answer (score 2):

according to your code:

```py
>>> compressed_json = data['base64(zip(o))']
>>> decompressed_json = zlib.decompress(b64decode(compressed))
>>> decompressed_json
b'"C:\\\\Users\\\\Beeri\\\\Google Drive\\\\Finance\\\\BPicks\\\\Stock Info\\\\daily data copy - Copy\\\\A.json"'
>>> json.loads(decompressed_json)
'C:\\Users\\Beeri\\Google Drive\\Finance\\BPicks\\Stock Info\\daily data copy - Copy\\A.json'
```

As mentioned by Karl, you basically compressed the file path not the actual file:
try this

```
import zlib, json
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

path = r"filename.json"

def compress_json(data):
    return {'base64(zip(o))': b64encode(zlib.compress(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'))).decode()}

def decompress_json(data):
    compressed_json =  data['base64(zip(o))']
    return json.loads(zlib.decompress(b64decode(compressed_json)))

with open(path, "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    compressed_json = compress_json(data)
    print(compressed_json)
    """
    {'base64(zip(o))': 'eJxTio7JUwCCaggFAjFKKYklqTFKVkCWkYGRga6Bqa6hhYKhmZW
    BARDFKOkgq80vSM0DqbUw1jO3RJHJyS+HSpiZo0hkZKZnYNeSnJNfnIpdU1l+TmkuWM7QwtT
    U0sQMIlmrQ7T7Ta1MLfG638LQFIcHzHF6wMIYpwfQ/IbsASMjEzNLcjxggdcDuMLf3AKX83EH
    P3pgIDvfwBgYBVDnx+TFKgEASGiHCQ=='}
    """
    decompressed_json = decompress_json(compressed_json)
    print(decompressed_json)
    """
[
    {
        "date": "2020-05-18 16:00:00",
        "open": 83.79,
        "low": 83.67,
        "high": 83.79,
        "close": 83.67,
        "volume": 1855946
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-05-18 15:59:00",
        "open": 83.815,
        "low": 83.77,
        "high": 83.83,
        "close": 83.79,
        "volume": 1822469
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-05-18 15:58:00",
        "open": 83.9,
        "low": 83.78,
        "high": 83.9,
        "close": 83.815,
        "volume": 1803855
    }
]
"""
```